# python how to open 2 data file every 100 step

Tags: python, numpy

Say, I have 20 interesting data files, taken two every hundred step, looks like:

1.dat, 2.dat, 101.dat, 102.dat, 201.dat, 202.dat.... 2001.dat, 2002.dat

how can I use `open` to fetch data from them? I wrote:

```
for t in range(1,2001, 100) and range(2, 2002, 100):
  f = open( str(t) +'.dat', 'r') 
y = np.array([[float(data) for data in line.split()] for line in f.readlines()])
f.close()
```

It seems this does not work, only `range(2,2002,100)` could be read.

Comment: `+i*100` would be my approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for t in range(1,2001, 100) + range(2, 2002, 100):
```

If you wanted sorted:

```
for t in sorted(range(1,2001, 100) + range(2, 2002, 100)):
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a combination of `zip` and `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

for t in chain.from_iterable(zip(range(1,2001,100), range(2, 2002, 100))):
    with open("{}.dat".format(t)) as f:
        y = np.array([[float(data) for data in line.split()] for line in f])
```

`zip` gives you a sequence with `(1,2), (101, 102), etc`. `chain.from_iterable` "flattens" the sequence to `1, 2, 101, 102, etc`.

A manual version of this might look like

```
for t in (x for y in range(1,2001,100) for x in (y, y+1)):
```

or a hybrid of the two:

```
for t in chain.from_iterable((x, x+1) for x in range(1, 2001, 100)):
```